# How to ensure one of the many jenkins job run at one time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have to test our application in Beta or qa. Only one user is allowed to log into one place at a time.

I have three node machines

- Windows
- Mac
- Ubuntu
- (Android is going to be added pretty soon)

On each node there are two jobs

- Beta
- QA

If Beta is running on one of the node. I don't want to run beta on any other node.

For example, I want to run of these jobs to be running at one time

- Windows Beta
- Mac Beta
- Ubuntu Beta
- (Android)

Similar is the case for QA.

I have seen that you can restrict only one job on the node. Which does not solve my problem. For example If beta and qa run on the same node it is acceptable.

So my question is how to make sure to restrict one of these job run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too simple of a solution and not sure if it will help you but

Create a Parent job, which calls these 4 jobs one after another, if you are using

> Parameterized Trigger Plugin

it will also let you

> block until the triggered projects finish their builds